# Calling Thread.sleep inside second Thread Object Method call

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm not sure how this will work, I create a Thread object `t1` and associate a method `DoStuff`, inside `DoStuff` I need to at some point call `Thread.Sleep(1000);` will this pause `t1` or the main thread or both.

```
var t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoStuff));
t1.Start();

public void DoStuff()
{
//some code then
Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will pause the `t1` thread for sure, but why don't just test it out yourself?